# Как правильно задать не стандартную ширину колонке Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Например, имеется 2 колонки, но ширина колонки в `col-sm-4` слишком мала, когда ширина колонки в `col-sm-5` уже слишком большая.

Каким образом в Bootstrap задается ширина колонки, которая например будет между указанных `col-sm-4` и `col-sm-5`?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4"></div>
<div class="col"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: надо добавить в CSS, `.col-sm-4{height: 200px;
    width: 50%;}`

Comment: @PauloBerezini свою дополнительную колонку, прописать ей все media итп? Или я что-то не правильно понял? А без влезания в CSS, родными способами Bootstrap можно решить эту задачу?

Comment: с помощью `media` bootstrap изменяет блок под размер экрана, например телефон или планшет или телевизор, что в вашем случае нужно, я не знаю, мало информации, можно это сделать с помощью `media`, но это не правильно, если вы хотите хард код прописать `width :30` например

Comment: я вкурсе, для чего нужны `media` запросы.
`надо добавить в CSS, .col-sm-4{height: 200px; width: 50%;}` - т.е. Вы предлагаете изменять структуру сетки Bootstrap?

Comment: `для создания адаптивной верстки` - это вопрос, утверждение или что?

Comment: Да я предлагаю изменять структуру блока Bootstrap через css(так и делается). Можно поставить `min-width` или `max-widt`, то что вам более подходит. Необязательно писать строго `width`